# <br> tag inside reqular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression

```
$rExp = '/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s"]{1,22}$/';
```

And check

```
if(preg_match($rExp, $userString)) {echo 'OK';}
```

My problem is that $userString can be like this:

```
$userString = 'Hello<br>hello';
```

I could modify regular expression like so:

```
$rExp = '/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s<>"]{1,22}$/';
```

But i dont like it because it accepts also script and other tags

How can i change regular expression so it only accepts br tag?

Thank you

Comment: Is it ok to replace `<br>` with space before the regexp check?

Comment: You're looking for exactly 1..22 characters. Will the `<br>` take you past that limit?

Comment: Good observation. I need to rethink character limit. @OnlineCop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming this is for some sort of input validation.

The proposed answer by [@onlineCop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801098/onlinecop) will work but i think it will be messing the "length" of the string, since a `<br>` tag will count as 4 chars.

Will it work? yes, sure. It's that the expected outcome? im not sure.

If thats works for you, excellent! I think it will be the fastest method, but with a *very* little overhead you can do this:

```
$maxLength = 22;

// As proposed by @onlineCop but without char count
$regEx = '^(?=(?:[0-9a-zA-Z\s"]|<br>)+$).+$'

/*
 * First: Does it has the valid length?
 * Second: Does it has only valid characters/tags?
 */
if (count(strip_tags($userString)) <= $maxLength) &&
  preg_match($regEx, $userString)) { 
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a look-ahead from the beginning of your line to validate the characters or words that follow will match your criteria, and then immediately follow that by length validation:

```
^(?=(?:[0-9a-zA-Z\s"]|<br>)+$).{1,22}$
```

You can add any single character you want into the `[...]` character group, and you can extend this with other items by using `|<something>` as much as you want.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bX2hG4/1)